# Complex constraints in Pyomo with Exists and forall quantifiers

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo

If I have a constraint reading like this:

```
For all a in A there exists a b in B so that for all c in C it holds 
that a variable x(a, b + c) is equal to a parameter m(a, c)
```

short:

```
forall a in A, exists b in B, forall c in C: x(a,b+c)=m(a,c)
```

I tried to create the constraint as follows:

```
constr = lambda model, a: any(all(model.x[a, b + c] <= model.m[a, c] for c in model.C[a]) for b in model.B if b + max(model.C[a]) <= max(model.B))
model.Constr = pyo.Constraint(model.A, rule = constr))
```

The variables and parameters follow [How to define in pyomo parameters representing differently sized vectors and sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703111/how-to-define-in-pyomo-parameters-representing-differently-sized-vectors-and-set) :

- `model.m[a, c]` are constructed as shown in  for `m.data` but with binary values
- `model.A` correspond to `m.nodes` with keys as integers (the keys of `some_vector`)
- `model.B` is `pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(1000)))`
- `model.C` corresponds to `m.elements`
- `model.x` is `pyo.Var(model.A, model.B, domain = pyo.Binary)`

currently I receive the following errors:

```
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: x[0,0]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0,0]
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint Constr2 with
    index 0: ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0,0]
ERROR: Constructing component 'Constr2' from data=None failed: ValueError: No
    value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0,0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gadget_chain.py", line 134, in <module>
    op.satisfiability_check(mgcm)
  File "optimise_payload.py", line 70, in satisfiability_check
    model.Constr2 = pyo.Constraint(model.Nodes, rule = constr2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 544, in __setattr__
    self.add_component(name, val)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 1089, in add_component
    val.construct(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/constraint.py", line 836, in construct
    index, self.rule(block, index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/util.py", line 304, in __call__
    return self._fcn(parent, idx)
  File "optimise_payload.py", line 69, in <lambda>
    any(all(model.x[node, addr + reg] == model.NodeRegisterUsage[node, reg] for reg in model.RegisterIndices[node]) for addr in model.Payload if addr + max(model.RegisterIndices[node]) <= max(model.Payload))
  File "optimise_payload.py", line 69, in <genexpr>
    any(all(model.x[node, addr + reg] == model.NodeRegisterUsage[node, reg] for reg in model.RegisterIndices[node]) for addr in model.Payload if addr + max(model.RegisterIndices[node]) <= max(model.Payload))
  File "pyomo/core/expr/logical_expr.pyx", line 304, in pyomo.core.expr.logical_expr.EqualityExpression.__nonzero__
  File "pyomo/core/expr/numeric_expr.pyx", line 218, in pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.ExpressionBase.__call__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 1054, in evaluate_expression
    return visitor.dfs_postorder_stack(exp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 584, in dfs_postorder_stack
    flag, value = self.visiting_potential_leaf(_sub)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 962, in visiting_potential_leaf
    return True, value(node)
  File "pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.pyx", line 246, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
  File "pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.pyx", line 233, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0,0]
```

The parameter are named differently here. I checked the constraints independent of one another and the error stays the same whether I comment the others or not. Therefore, the error has to be corresponding with this constraint.

In general feel free to also propose more efficient ways of creating constraints in Pyomo. I am a total beginner with this software.

Comment: It's not real clear what you are trying to do in this case, but sadly `max()`, `any()`, and `all()` are nonlinear constructs that are illegal in `pyomo` ... meaning they do not produce recognizable expressions that `pyomo` is trying to build to hand to the solver.  You'll have to re-formulate whatever it is you have packed into that constraint.  ;)

Comment: @AirSquid you are completely right and I just didn't notice that exists in this contexts means that only a subset of the constraints have to be true - currently I slightly question whether this constraint can be somehow reformulated. Tried to explain it as well as I can here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8588/reformulating-a-constraint-that-is-non-linear because I just don't see how. General geometric knapsack problems seem to be solvable with ILPs ( Optimal Solutions for a Geometric Knapsack Problem
using Integer Programming - Paper). My problem should be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
 forall a in A, exists b in B, forall c in C: x(a,b+c)=m(a,c)
```

We miss a lot of details, and I am a bit confused by your non-standard description, but my guess is that you mean :

```
    x[a,1+c] = m[a,c] or x[a,2+c] = m[a,c] or ...   ∀a,c
```

For the last `c` this has no meaning. So not sure what you want to do then.

These `or` conditions can be handled with disjunctions in Pyomo or using binary or SOS1 variables.